# Connection timeout when connecting to Elasticsearch using eland

Tags: elasticsearch, eland

I'm trying to connect to my 3-node Elasticsearch (version 8.3.3) cluster remotely, using the eland library. I'm trying out with just one of the nodes first. This node has the following configuration in `elasticsearch.yml`.

```
network.host: 1.2.3.4

xpack.security.enabled: true

xpack.security.http.ssl:
  enabled: false

xpack.security.transport.ssl:
  enabled: true
  verification_mode: certificate
  keystore.path: xxx
  truststore.path: xxx
```

`http.host` and `transport.host` are both commented out in the config file.

I have the following code in another server in Jupyter Notebook.

```
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch
import eland as ed

es = Elasticsearch([{'host': "1.2.3.4", 'port': 9200, 'scheme': 'http'}], basic_auth=("xxx","yyy"), request_timeout=120)

index="abc"
fields=["@timestamp", "fieldA", "fieldB"]

df = ed.DataFrame(es, index, columns=fields)
```

I keep getting `Connection timed out`. Just running `es.info()` also gets a `Connection timed out` error.

What can I do?

Answer (score 0):

## Tldr

I believe it could be because of the scheme you are using.

Shouldn't you be using `https` ?

## Solution

```py
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch
import eland as ed

es = Elasticsearch([{'host': "1.2.3.4", 'port': 9200, 'scheme': 'https'}], basic_auth=("xxx","yyy"), request_timeout=120)
                                                                 ^^^^^ here
index="abc"
fields=["@timestamp", "fieldA", "fieldB"]

df = ed.DataFrame(es, index, columns=fields)
```

Comment: I've tried with the scheme set to `https`, then `es.info()`, but it still gave the `Connection timed out` error.

Comment: Are you sure your cluster is up and running ? Have you taken a look into the logs of Elasticsearch ?

Comment: Yes, it is up and running. I've been monitoring it on Kibana, and it has been indexing documents for days. There isn't anything on the elasticsearch logs about trying to connect to it remotely.